# NTLMv2 authentication in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

QNetworkAccessManager emits the

```
authenticationRequired (QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator*)
```

signal when authentication is required. This can be used for basic authentication.

But how to make a Qt program to do NTLM authentication with the server ? I couldnt find examples for this anywhere.

Comment: Which Qt version do you use? Qt 4.8 and Qt 5 apparently support NTLMv2: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qauthenticator.html , http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qauthenticator.html

Comment: Yes, they support NTLMv2. My question is .. when authentication required signal is emitted, how to instruct qt to do ntlmv2 authentication ? if we set the username to domainname\username, will qt automatically do ntlm authentication ?

Comment: I would assume the authentification method is detected. Did you try?

Comment: Yes I did try. It didn't do automatically ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get this to work on Qt 4.8, but on Qt 5.1 it kind of works. The QAuthenticator works really badly in this case. If you want to set the username and password manually in the slot that processes the authenticationRequired signal:

```
onAuthenticationRequired (QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator* auth)
{
    auth->setUser("username");
    auth->setPassword("password");
}
```

However, if you want to use the current Windows user login, you need to set the username as an empty string:

```
onAuthenticationRequired (QNetworkReply*, QAuthenticator* auth)
{
    auth->setUser("");
}
```

**NOTE:** This slot will be called 4 times even when the Windows user is granted access. This is especially frustrating if the user is supposed to provide the credentials. Additionally the QAuthenticator does not provide any public methods to figure out which authentication method is actually being used.

Comment: In addition to what Lauri Soini answered, one interesting observation if you want to use the current Windows login: if you pass a random password and a empty username with the url, then the `authenticationRequired` signal won't even be emitted once (let alone four times), i.e. `http://:randompwd@host`.

Comment: @smani Does HTTPS with QAuthenticator + NTLMv2 work for you? 
HTTP works fine for me, but not HTTPS.