# NTLM authentication using qt

Tags: c++, qt, ntlm

I'm writing client app for windows (using qt webkit). Web server which i tying to connect provides ntlm authentication (Active Directory). How can I make transparent authentication in qt using user windows credentials?
I found that QAuthenticator supports NTLMv2 but i didn't find any examples how to implement it using user windows stored credentials.

Comment: Have you considered using qt5? Documentation claims it should work out-of-the-box - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qauthenticator.html#ntlm-version-2.

Comment: I'm using qt4.8 and yes there is a support of NTLMv2 in QAuthenticator but I can't get it work. As mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706851/ntlmv2-authentication-in-qt it's not working in qt4.8

Comment: link in first comment is dead now.
Here is new link location: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qauthenticator.html